# get the expanding node in a treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a treeview control that functions like a folder browser.
Because loading the entire folder structer from disk is taking a lot of time i'm trying to load only one level at a time.
So i have a function that adds nodes for all the folders in the current node.

I thought that the best method would be to run it on the `BeforeExpand` event of the treeview.

```
UpdateTreeView(TreeView.SelectedNode);
```

is not working because clicking the + sign to expand is not selecting the node also.

So how  to find the node that is expanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `BeforeExpand` event should work. It has a `TreeViewCancelEventArgs` which contains a `Node` property. It is essentially the node being expanded.